# Why giving a host alias does not work with an Ansible Inventory file?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory, ansible-ad-hoc

production (inventory file):

```
#main ansible_host=54.293.2785.210 ansible_port=22 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
54.293.2785.210 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
```

Running an ad-hoc command: `ansible all -i production -a "hostname"` **Works!**

But when I uncomment the first line and comment the second:
`ansible main -i production -a "hostname" -vvvv`

Gives the following error:

```
main | FAILED => SSH Error: ssh: Could not resolve hostname main: Name or service not known
It is sometimes useful to re-run the command using -vvvv, which prints SSH debug output to help diagnose the issue.
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ansible_host` is the [new (>=2.0) syntax](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_inventory.html#hosts-and-groups).

Before that is was simply `ansible_ssh_host` but this has been deprecated in the more recent versions of Ansible (>=2.0):

> Ansible 2.0 has deprecated the “ssh” from ansible_ssh_user, ansible_ssh_host, and ansible_ssh_port to become ansible_user, ansible_host, and ansible_port. If you are using a version of Ansible prior to 2.0, you should continue using the older style variables (ansible_ssh_*). These shorter variables are ignored, without warning, in older versions of Ansible.

If you're using an earlier version of Ansible then `ansible_ssh_host` should work for you.